# In the Walking Dead, where and when did the infection start?

Tags: the-walking-dead

Where and when did the infection start? I'm curious because it isn't explained in *The Walking Dead*. If it was then I will have to start it all over again.

Comment: Comic or TV series?

Comment: Answers on the other question cover both the show and comics, and the lack of origin that will ever be given.

Comment: Hasn't the creator said he will not reveal this? So basically, it is all speculation.